# Concatenating two lists of Strings element wise in Python without Nested for loops

Tags: python, string, concatenation, nested-loops

I have two lists of strings:
      `ls1 = ['a','b','c','d']` and `ls2 = ['k','j','l','m']`

I want to create  a 3rd list: `ls3 = ['a-k','a-j','a-l','a-m','b-k','b-j','b-l','b-m'...'d-m']` which has 16 elements.

I can achieve this quite easily with the following nested `for` loops

```
ls3 = [] 
for elem in ls1:
    for item in ls2:
        ls3.append(elem+'-'+item)
```

However, this isn't very Pythonic and reveals my C-code background.

I attempted a more Pythonic solution with `map` and `lambda`:

```
[ map(lambda x,y: x+'-'+y, a,b) for a,b in zip(ls1,ls2) ]
```

But I don't really know what I'm doing yet.

**What is a Pythonic way to achieve what I've done with my nested `for` loops?**

Comment: Your nested for-loops *are* Pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique you have used is perfectly Pythonic, and until list comprehensions were introduced into the language would have been canonical. The one you suggest using `zip`, however, won't work, because you want all pairs of elements from `ls1` and `ls2`, but `zip` simply creates pairs using the corresponding elements rather than all combinations.

If you'd like to use more compact code then the appropriate list comprehension would be

```
ls3 = [x+'-'+y for x in ls1 for y in ls2]
```

For large lists, or where you need every ounce of performance (which should never be your first consideration) see the answer from @PaulPanzer, who explains a more efficient though slightly more complex technique.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.product` together with `map`:

```
list(map('-'.join, itertools.product('abcd', 'kjlm')))
# ['a-k', 'a-j', 'a-l', 'a-m', 'b-k', 'b-j', 'b-l', 'b-m', 'c-k', 'c-j', 'c-l', 'c-m', 'd-k', 'd-j', 'd-l', 'd-m']
```

Test for correctness and timings:

The usual disclaimers for benchmarks apply.

Under the test conditions the above ("`product map`") solution is faster than the "naive" list comprehension ("`naive`"), although the margin is small for small problem size.

Much of the speed-up appears to be due to avoiding a list comprehension. Indeed if `map` is replaced by a list comprehension ("`product compr`") then `product` still scales better than the naive approach, but at small problem size falls behind:

```
small (4x4)
results equal: True True
naive             0.002420 ms
product compr     0.003211 ms
product map       0.002146 ms
large (4x4x4x4x4x4)
results equal: True True
naive             0.836124 ms
product compr     0.681193 ms
product map       0.385240 ms
```

Benchmark script for reference

```
import itertools
import timeit

lists = [[chr(97 + 4*i + j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(6)]

print('small (4x4)')
print('results equal:', [x+'-'+y for x in lists[0] for y in lists[1]]
      ==
      list(map('-'.join, itertools.product(lists[0], lists[1]))), end=' ')
print(['-'.join(t) for t in  itertools.product(lists[0], lists[1])]
      ==
      list(map('-'.join, itertools.product(lists[0], lists[1]))))

print('{:16s} {:9.6f} ms'.format('naive', timeit.timeit(lambda: [x+'-'+y for x in lists[0] for y in lists[1]], number=1000)))
print('{:16s} {:9.6f} ms'.format('product compr', timeit.timeit(lambda: ['-'.join(t) for t in itertools.product(lists[0], lists[1])], number=1000)))
print('{:16s} {:9.6f} ms'.format('product map', timeit.timeit(lambda: list(map('-'.join, itertools.product(lists[0], lists[1]))), number=1000)))

print('large (4x4x4x4x4x4)')
print('results equal:', ['-'.join((u, v, w, x, y, z)) for u in lists[0] for v in lists[1] for w in lists[2] for x in lists[3] for y in lists[4] for z in lists[5]]
      ==
      list(map('-'.join, itertools.product(*lists))), end=' ')
print(['-'.join(t) for t in  itertools.product(*lists)]
      ==
      list(map('-'.join, itertools.product(*lists))))

print('{:16s} {:9.6f} ms'.format('naive', timeit.timeit(lambda: ['-'.join((u, v, w, x, y, z)) for u in lists[0] for v in lists[1] for w in lists[2] for x in lists[3] for y in lists[4] for z in lists[5]], number=1000)))
print('{:16s} {:9.6f} ms'.format('product compr', timeit.timeit(lambda: ['-'.join(t) for t in  itertools.product(*lists)], number=1000)))
print('{:16s} {:9.6f} ms'.format('product map', timeit.timeit(lambda: list(map('-'.join, itertools.product(*lists))), number=1000)))
```

Comment: This quite unnecessarily uses a library module to provide a solution that will work more quickly using only built-in language constructs (though it does have the merit of answering the OP's question of how to avoid nested loops, it does so at significant cost).

Comment: I think @holdenweb is being unnecessarily critical. This solution is faster than the list comprehension approach, makes it explicitly clear that it's generating a product of the inputs, and can be easily generalized to any number of inputs. I think both answers teach something useful.

Comment: Ah, a voice of moderation. Thank you @mfripp, your comment is most welcome.

Comment: Criticism does not necessarily imply disapproval. @PaulPanzer has clearly demonstrated that I was wrong to assert the use of a library module was "quite unnecessary." More credit to him for the extra work he put in. I have withdrawn my down vote.

Comment: @holdenweb *"Criticism does not necessarily imply disapproval."* It usually does when it is reinforced by a downvote. Anyway, thanks for coming back on this, it is appreciated.

Comment: In which case I'm glad I took the time