# Combining lists within a nested list, if lists contain the same element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have nested list that has a structure similar to this, except it's obviously much longer:

```
mylist = [ ["Bob", "12-01 2:30"], ["Sal", "12-01 5:23"], ["Jill", "12-02 1:28"] ]
```

My goal is to create another nested lists that **combines** all elements that have the same date. So, the following output is desired:

```
newlist = [  [["Bob", "12-01 2:30"], ["Sal", "12-01 5:23"]], [["Jill", "12-02 1:28"]]  ]
```

Above, all items with the date 12-01, regardless of time, are combined, and all elements of 12-02 are combined.

I've sincerely been researching how to do this for the past 1 hour and can't find anything. Furthermore, I'm a beginner at programming, so I'm not skilled enough to try to create my own solution. So, please don't think that I haven't attempted to do research or put any effort into trying this problem myself. I'll add a few links as examples of my research below:

[Collect every pair of elements from a list into tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647050/collect-every-pair-of-elements-from-a-list-into-tuples-in-python)

[Create a list of tuples with adjacent list elements if a condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251245/create-a-list-of-tuples-with-adjacent-list-elements-if-a-condition-is-true)

[How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

[Concatenating two lists of Strings element wise in Python without Nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386075/concatenating-two-lists-of-strings-element-wise-in-python-without-nested-for-loo)

[Zip two lists together based on matching date in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290150/zip-two-lists-together-based-on-matching-date-in-string)

[How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/how-to-merge-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dict or orderdict(if the sort is important) group data by the date time .

```py
from collections import defaultdict # use defaultdict like {}.setdefault(), it's very facility

mylist = [["Bob", "12-01 2:30"], ["Sal", "12-01 5:23"], ["Jill", "12-02 1:28"]]
record_dict = defaultdict(list)
# then iter the list group all date time.

for data in mylist:
    _, time = data
    date_time, _ = time.split(" ")
    record_dict[date_time].append(data)

res_list = list(record_dict.values())
print(res_list)
```

output:
`[[['Bob', '12-01 2:30'], ['Sal', '12-01 5:23']], [['Jill', '12-02 1:28']]]`

Answer (score 4):

A pure list-based solution as an alternative to the accepted dictionary-based solution. This offers the additional feature of easily sorting the whole list, first by date, then by hour, then by name

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [["Bob", "12-01 2:30"], ["Sal", "12-01 5:23"], ["Jill", "12-02 1:28"]]

newlist = [dt.split() + [name] for (name, dt) in mylist]
newlist.sort() # can be removed if inital data is already sorted by date
newlist = [list(group) for (date, group) in groupby(newlist, lambda item:item[0])]

# result:
# [[['12-01','2:30','Bob'], ['12-01','5:23','Sal']], [['12-02','1:28','Jill']]]
```

If you really want the same item format as the initial list, it requires a
double iteration:

```
newlist = [[[name, date + ' ' + time] for (date, time, name) in group]
           for (date, group) in groupby(newlist, lambda item:item[0])]

# result:
# [[['Bob', '12-01 2:30'], ['Sal', '12-01 5:23']], [['Jill', '12-02 1:28']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind going heavy on your memory usage, you can try using a dictionary. You can use the date as the key and make a list of values.

```py
all_items = {}
for line in myList:
    x, y = line
    date, time = y.split()
    try:
        all_items[date].append(line)
    except:
        all_items[date] = [line,]
```

Then, you can create a new list using the sorted date for keys.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the elements with the same date are consecutive, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
list(map(list, groupby(data, lambda value: ...)))
```