# Grouping elements time-wise in a date-wise nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list that has this type of structure:

```
mylist = [

[
    ['Bob', 'Male', '2019-12-10 9:00'], 
    ['Sally', 'Female', '2019-12-10 15:00']
], 

[
    ['Jake', 'Male', '2019-12-12 9:00'], 
    ['Ally', 'Female', '2019-12-12 9:30'], 
    ['Jamal', 'Male', '2019-12-12 15:00']
], 

[
    ['Andy', 'Male', '2019-12-13 15:00'],
    ['Katie', 'Female', '2019-12-13 15:30']
]

]
```

Currently, this master list `mylist` is organized by date. All elements containing the same day (i.e. 2019-12-12, 2019-12-13...) are nested together.

I'd like to take this nesting one step further and create another nested group inside that date-wise nested group. This time, I'd like to organize them time-wise. I would like to group all people that have a tag at hour 9 together, and people with a tag at hour 15 together.

So, I'm trying to get this output:

```
newlist = [

[
  [
    ['Bob', 'Male', '2019-12-10 9:00']
  ], 
  [
    ['Sally', 'Female', '2019-12-10 15:00']
  ]
], 


[
  [
    ['Jake', 'Male', '2019-12-12 9:00'], 
    ['Ally', 'Female', '2019-12-12 9:30'], 
  ],
  [
    ['Jamal', 'Male', '2019-12-12 15:00']
  ]
], 


[
  [
    ['Andy', 'Male', '2019-12-13 15:00'],
    ['Katie', 'Female', '2019-12-13 15:30']
  ]
]


]
```

Based on the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366840/combining-lists-within-a-nested-list-if-lists-contain-the-same-element) question, I modified and tried to use the following code, but it didn't work.

```
newdict = defaultdict(list)

for data in mylist:
    for datum in data:
        _, _, time = datum
        _, date_time = time.split(" ")
        _, hour_minute = date_time.split(":")
        newdict[hour_minute].append(datum)

newlist = list(newdict.values())
print(newlist)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:

[
  [
     ['Bob', 'Male', '2019-12-10 9:00'], 
     ['Sally', 'Female', '2019-12-10 15:00'], 
     ['Jake', 'Male', '2019-12-12 9:00'], 
     ['Ally', 'Female', '2019-12-12 9:30'], 
     ['Jamal', 'Male', '2019-12-12 15:00'], 
     ['Andy', 'Male', '2019-12-13 15:00'],
     ['Katie', 'Female', '2019-12-13 15:30']
  ]
]
```

I've also done a lot of online searching and couldn't find any solutions. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Also, please keep in mind that I'm new to programming, so please try to keep answers/explanations as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Are the entries in the sublists sorted by timestamp?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Hi Patrick, yes, they are all already in order by date, hour, minute. So, the order doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're already in order, we can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a function to isolate the hour to group them:

```
from itertools import groupby


def f(l):
    return l[2].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0]

newlist = [[list(g) for _, g in groupby(subl, f)] for subl in mylist]
```

results in

```
[
  [
    [
      ['Bob', 'Male', '2019-12-10 9:00']
    ],
    [ 
      ['Sally', 'Female', '2019-12-10 15:00']
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      ['Jake', 'Male', '2019-12-12 9:00'], 
      ['Ally', 'Female', '2019-12-12 9:30']
    ],
    [
      ['Jamal', 'Male', '2019-12-12 15:00']
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      ['Andy', 'Male', '2019-12-13 15:00'],
      ['Katie', 'Female', '2019-12-13 15:30']
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
def group_l(d): 
  return [list(b) for _, b in gb(_d, key=lambda x:x[-1].split()[-1].split(':')[0]))]


result = list(map(group_l, mylist))
```

Output:

```
[
 [
   [
     ['Bob', 'Male', '2019-12-10 9:00']
   ], 
   [
     ['Sally', 'Female', '2019-12-10 15:00']
   ]
 ], 
 [
   [
    ['Jake', 'Male', '2019-12-12 9:00'], 
    ['Ally', 'Female', '2019-12-12 9:30']
   ], 
   [['Jamal', 'Male', '2019-12-12 15:00']]
  ], 
 [
   [
     ['Andy', 'Male', '2019-12-13 15:00'], 
     ['Katie', 'Female', '2019-12-13 15:30']
   ]
  ]
 ]
```